# Why is $0$ a zero divisor?

Tags: ring-theory, soft-question, terminology

Why do some sources define zero divisors in such a way that $0$ is a zero divisor? Does it not make things confusing? For example, in this terminology integral domains actually have zero divisors, but have no **non-zero** zero divisors. To me it seems that since $0$ acts "the same" in any ring, then there is nothing to win from bringing it "into equation".

Comment: You do have a point. I can't see what we gain from that terminology.

Comment: I've never seen a text allow $0$ to be a zero-divisor.  I believe you that they exist, but...

Comment: @Randall. Here are two sources that I know of: Aluffi's Algebra Chapter 0 and wikipedia.

Comment: There is some theorem for certain readers it’s (commutative noetherian, I think) where the set of zero divisors is the union of minimal primes. It seems pretty awkward to me to have to say “the union of minimal primes is the set of zero divisors along with zero”.  I try to avoid definitions which make exceptions, where possible. There are some cases where it is unavoidable of course. Ultimately it’s just a matter of convenience for the author. Personally excluding 0 seems unnatural, but I understand the use of that convention.

Comment: If you consider that nearly every geometry book in the US written for primary education says that a trapezoid has *exactly* one pair of parallel sides, then you can get a feel for why exceptions in definitions  annoy me.

Comment: @Randall: Another example: Atiyah & Macdonald (p. 2). I completely agree with rschwieb here. The way I think about it is $$\{ 0 \} \subseteq \{ \text{nilpotent elements} \} \subseteq \{ \text{zero-divisors} \} \subseteq R$$ and it is interesting to ask whether the various set inclusions are strict or not.

Comment: I'm disappointed that I am so concerned about this.  "An integral domain is a commutative ring with identity without zero divisors, except for $0$."  Can't do it.

Comment: @Randall That is one of the "unavoidable" cases I was willing to concede where the exception is better than adopting the exception into the definition of zero divisor. Similarly, when we define fields, we have to say "every element *except 0* is invertible."  Or maybe the definition of "integral domain" is just stupid. Maybe all the books should say "the collection of nonzero elements is a monoid" and the definition of field should be "the collection of nonzero elements is a group."

Comment: @Randall Imagine this "dual" situation. Suppose we studied rings which only had $1$ as a unit.  Doesn't it strike you as a little weird to say "a regular element is an element for which multiplication is injective and which *is not 1*?"  It would be a fair objection to say that I don't have any theorems in mind which would benefit from this choice of terminology, but it seems to highlight the same discrepancy all the same.

Comment: @Randall And sorry, perhaps I'm reading your comment "Can't do it" in the opposite way you intended (it's unclear.) Does "it" mean "include 0 as a zero divisor" or "exclude zero as a zero divisor"?

Comment: @rschwieb  I meant "can't do it" in the former, because it makes the definition of integral domain wonky.  I do like your monoid/group alternative, though.

Answer (score 1):

Caution, the subring {0} of ℤ has no zero divisor. ℤ₁ has no zero divisor, too.

The essential notion behind all 'zero divisor' terms seems to be this, R ring:
It's trivial that each element x of R left-divides 0 in the sense that 0=xy for y=0, but it's much less trivial that there's an element y≠0. (The same holds for right division.)

I think of 'ring zero divisor' as any 'element capable of multiplicatively reaching 0 without resorting to 0 as *multiplier*'.

Edit:
There's been some debate about proper definition of 'zero divisor'. Philosophically, this should be taken seriously. After all, maybe we are dealing with (slightly) different concepts? Above, I present one such concept.

Answer (score 0):

I think the whole issue of whether $0$ is or is not a $0$-divisor can be resolved by just a few added words of context... rather than trying to achieve some perfect, absolute definition. (Similar to how $1$ was conventionally a prime until some point in the 19th century, when people collectively agreed that it was more convenient, for statement of various theorems, to say that $1$ is *not* prime.

Similarly, I'd advocate saying $0$ is not a *proper* $0$-divisor, although, yes, by anyone's definition of divisibility, $0$ does divide $0$. That's just not interesting. :)

In recent years, I've more-and-more tried to emphasize to students that there is an enormous difference between *conventions* ("definitions"? terminology?) and mathematical *facts*. Facts do not depend on context/language. :)

E.g., $R=\{0\}$ is a ring, by some definitions, but $0=1$. Maybe it's a field, too? But/and if we declare that "field" only allows $0\not=1$, then what is this thing? :)

And $3\mathbb Z/6$ is certainly some kind of subring of $\mathbb Z/6$, and it has unit $3$ (mod $6$), but that unit is not the unit of $\mathbb Z/6$. Nothing pathological here... but only illustrating the *mathematical* *fact* that ring (with unit) inclusions need not map $1$ to $1$, so that that might have to be added as a requirement, if it is desired. :)